# Potential Memory Leak or Incorrect Decrement of the reference count

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I have this method which

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        UIWebView *t_webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 
                                                                       320,480)];
        self.webView = t_webView;
        self.accel = [[Accelerometer alloc]init];

        //Potential Memory Leak here
        NSURL *theurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"second" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"www"]];
        [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theurl]];
        [self.view addSubview:webView];

        [theurl release];//When I add this line, the Memory Leak Warning disappears, but instead I get a "incorrect Decrement of reference count
        theurl = nil;

        [t_webView release];
    }

    return self;
 }
```

I think I haven´t understood something about memory management, can somebody help me how to avoid the warning?

Comment: How do you declare your properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSURL *theurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"second" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"www"]];
```

That returns an autoreleased object.   `release`ing it later in the method is incorrect.

The leak is `self.accel = [[Accelerometer alloc]init];`;   +alloc implies a `retain` and the assignment to a retaining property is the other.  I would suggest:

```
Accelerometer *acc = [[Accelerometer alloc]init];
self.accel = acc;
... do stuff with `acc` ...
[acc release];
```

If the compiler warning comes and goes w/`[theurl release]`, that sounds like an analyzer bug.

Comment: What about `self.accel = [[[Accelerometer alloc] init] autorelease];`?